# how to add item to paged list

Tags: android, paging

now i'm using google paging library in chat fragment

here's code inside initial in my data source :

```
    Disposable disposable = apiWrapper.getMessages(1, userId)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(messagesPagingResponse -> {
                        if (messagesPagingResponse.getData() != null && messagesPagingResponse.getData().getData() != null) {
                            callback.onResult(messagesPagingResponse.getData().getData(), null, messagesPagingResponse.getData().getNextPage());
                        }
                    }

    , throwable -> {
                        Log.e("throwable", throwable.getLocalizedMessage());
                    });
    compositeDisposable.add(disposable);
```

and in chat fragment i observe the list

```
        viewModel.getLiveMessages().observe(this, this::setChatList);




 private void setChatList(PagedList<Message> messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
        ChatPagingAdapter chatPagingAdapter = (ChatPagingAdapter) binding.messagesRecyclerView.getAdapter();
        if (chatPagingAdapter != null){
            chatPagingAdapter.submitList(this.messages);
        }
    }
```

it working well until iam trying to add new message to paged list so it show me this error

```
E/error: The exception could not be delivered to the consumer because it has already canceled/disposed the flow or the exception has nowhere to go to begin with. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#error-handling | java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

when i get new message i try to add it as this

```
                            messages.add(0, message);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Paging Library doesn't currently allow you to add items to the PagedAdapter like it is done for the normal RecyclerView. All updates must come from the datasource.

What I did in a similar situation to yours is persist all chat messages using Room and build the `PagedList` `LiveData` with a `DataSource.Factory` from the `Dao`(Data Access Object). Whenever there is a new message, all you have to do is persist that message,then room sends the update to your `PagedList` `Livedata` and your Chats RecyclerView updates accordingly.

If you are unfamiliar with Room you can read more from the [offical documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room)

Comment: i am familiar with room,

Comment: do you mean i should get all messages from backend then put it all in database then

Comment: how i can migrate paging and room or what to write in loadinitial and load after

Comment: Instead of creating your own datasource factory you can return a datasource factory from a room query and use that to build your LiveData<PageList<Message>>

Comment: You can load a reasonable amount of previous messages from backend if no message exist locally when the user visits the chat.

Comment: I was using cloud messaging to send and receive and save new messages to database instead of having to check backend every time for messages.

Comment: For cloud messaging you can check out Google Cloud messaging  here https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: Using room with paging library you can check out this link https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-architecture-components-using-the-paging-library-with-room--cms-31535

Comment: @Networks do you mind sharing the code?